# PLACEHOLDER: Typo Finder Bot (Stack Overflow)

Tags: app, placeholder, chatbot, api-v2.3

This is a post is to announce the development of a bot (which will be running on the account [Secretary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17767273)), whose task is to find posts in need of some formatting/editing help.

The goal is to use a combination of heuristics, spelling and grammar rules, and some machine learning to find and detect potentially good questions and answers that would be improved by small tweaks.

Currently under development and testing.